# USB reformat via terminal

Tags: formatting

I used the following command to reformat my usb,

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
```

But now (thunar) it says root is the owner and I can't write to the disk.

Screenshot:
[Thunar sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix9Ji.png)

Comment: can you run a  'ls -l /dev/sdb1'

Comment: @INDIVIDUAL-IT  `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Dec 18 20:43 /dev/sdb1`

Answer (score 0):

You should unplug the flash drive, then plug it again. FAT32 doesn't keep permissions, so when you replug the drive, permissions will be configured by automount. Assuming automount is set up correctly (i.e. you can use other USB drives with no issues), it will set the owner to the currenty logged user, allowing you to write.

Comment: That doesn't do anything. Look at the screen shot I added. I plugged into two usbs: 
32G doesn't have any issues and mounted automatically, 
Lexar has the issue and fails to mount even manually.